# How can Java stream reduce accumulator parameter be associative

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

The question is about

```
java.util.stream.Stream.reduce(U identity,
             BiFunction<U, ? super T, U> accumulator,
             BinaryOperator<U> combiner)
```

method.

From the API docs:

> accumulator – an **associative**, non-interfering, stateless function for
>   incorporating an additional element into a result

Now, the definition of *associative* is:

```
(a op b) op c = a op (b op c) for all a, b, c
```

As we can see, the above definition requires a BinaryOperator, not only a BiFunction, because `a op b` requires `b` of type `T` while `b op c` requires `b` of type `U`. If `U` and `T` are distinct, this is impossible.

---

**My question**

How can the definition of *associative* be formulated for a BiFunction that is not a BinaryOperator?

---

**UPDATE**

I have submitted a bug to Oracle about this issue, with the internal review ID : 9063337

I will update the question with Oracle's feedback.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206180/discussion-on-question-by-eugen-covaci-how-can-java-stream-reduce-accumulator-pa).

Answer (score 4):

Mind [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-):

> Additionally, the `combiner` function must be compatible with the `accumulator` function; for all `u` and `t`, the following must hold:
>
> ```
> combiner.apply(u, accumulator.apply(identity, t)) == accumulator.apply(u, t)
> ```

<sup>whereas `==` is not to be taken literally but rather means “equivalent result”</sup>

So in fact, we have a much stronger constraint on `accumulator` than associativity, as it must be compatible with the `combiner`, which is an associative function.

There’s also the API Note:

> Many reductions using this form can be represented more simply by an explicit combination of map and reduce operations. The accumulator function acts as a fused mapper and accumulator, which can sometimes be more efficient than separate mapping and reduction, …

When the `accumulator` function is a fused mapping and reduction function, only the reduction part must be associative. When you want to test that part, just test whether the `combiner` function fulfills the associativity constraint and whether `combiner` and `accumulator` are compatible in the specified way. If both are proven, the associativity of the `accumulator`’s reduction part has been proven too.

While the API Note says “many reductions using this form”, actually *all of them* can be expressed as an explicit combination of map and reduce operations, when we ignore the efficiency, due to the specified constraints:

```
Function<T,U> mappingFunc = t -> accumulator.apply(identitiy, t);
U result = streamOfT.map(mappingFunc).reduce(identitiy, combiner);
```

This `result` must be equivalent to the result of, e.g. a typical sequential evaluation of `streamOfT.reduce(identitiy, accumulator, combiner)`, which doesn’t use the `combiner` at all.

We can formulate narrow test cases for the associativity as

```
U u1 = accumulator.apply(accumulator.apply(identitiy, t1), t2);
U u2 = combiner.apply(accumulator.apply(identitiy, t1), accumulator.apply(identitiy, t2));
```

where `u1` and `u2` must be equivalent results, as well as

```
U u1 = accumulator.apply(accumulator.apply(accumulator.apply(identitiy, t1), t2), t3);
U u2 = combiner.apply(accumulator.apply(identitiy, t1),
           accumulator.apply(accumulator.apply(identitiy, t2), t3));
```